# Raspberry PI 3 Time sync interval configuration

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have made time-sensitive application for Raspberry Pi.

However, I found that my RPi showed 5~6 sec error per day.

Therefore I need to do time sync more frequently.

I had been searched many QnAs but I cannot found accurate answers.

Comment: Are you using NTP or a RTC?

Comment: Could you provide links to the many inaccurate answers you have tried so we do not give them as answers?

Comment: @MatsK Raspbian Stretch doesn't used NTP. It was updated to use the slightly inferior timesyncd. Default poll time is 32s at startup then switches to 2048s when the clock is sync'd.

Comment: @Dougie Stretch DOES use NTP - it just uses timesyncd as NTP client rather than the more complex ntpd

Comment: @Milliways your definition of "uses ntp" clearly differs from mine. I meant it doesn't use a local ntp daemon.

Comment: @Dougie I said "NTP" i.e. Network Time Protocol as documented in RFC5905